# Change bottom line color from Blue to something when in Action Mode

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

[image]I want to know that can we change the bottom line color when user long press on list item and action mode is activated. In the Screenshot you can see that the bottom line color in action mode is blue. I want to change it to orange so that it matches my layout colors. I tried with this:

```
<item name="android:actionmodebackground">@color/orange</item>
```

but it changes the whole background to orange but i just want to change the bottom line color. is it possible? Any link or code snippet will be appreciated.

Comment: hey, do you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this function :

```
public static void tintView(View view, int color) {
    final Drawable d = view.getBackground();
    final Drawable nd = d.getConstantState().newDrawable();
    nd.setColorFilter(AppCompatDrawableManager.getPorterDuffColorFilter(
        color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    view.setBackground(nd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@android:color/white</item>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with?

```
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/orange</item>
```